# How to set the indent of XmlWriterSettings in a class, derived from XmlObjectSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am extending `XmlObjectSerializer` and i would like to configure the indent of it, but it is inside the `XmlWriterSettings` member and that is read only. From the documentation i can see that it can be set only when creating an `XmlWriter` instance like:

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings);
```

But i don't create one. I create my class `XmlObjectWithRefSerializer`, derived from `XmlObjectSerializer`, like this:

```
StreamWriter swWriter = File.CreateText(sFilename);
var serializer = new XmlObjectWithRefSerializer(tType);
serializer.WriteObject(swWriter.BaseStream, oData);
swWriter.Close();
```

Inside my class, it is used as `XmlDictionaryWriter` in methods i have to override like:

```
public override void WriteObjectContent(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.Indent = true;
    //writer.Settings = settings;  --> Fails because read only
    ...
}
```

So, is there a way to give settings to my derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I don't think you can.

The `Settings` property (of type `XmlWriterSettings`) on the abstract `XmlWriter` class is defined as virtual, so can be overridden in subclasses, however this would not help in your scenario.

You are calling the `WriteObject` method, passing the stream to write to. What happens next is that, in the `XmlObjectSerializer` class, the method will create a new `XmlDictionaryWriter` (which is just a wrapper around the supplied stream) that then gets passed to the methods that you override (`WriteObjectContent` et al).

It would appear that at no point is there a hook you can use to replace the writer settings with your own.